# a particular case of using Past Simple instead of Present Perfect

Tags: grammar

I have come across the following dialogue in New Round-Up 3 (Pearson Education Limited, 2010): 
Policeman: Where were you last night?
Mr Laton: I went to the Rex cinema with my wife.
Policeman: That is very strange, Mr Laton. That cinema was closed last night.
Mr. Laton: Oh yes, I *made* a mistake. It was last week. Last night, I umm...
Policeman: *Did* you *forget*?

Why isn't it 'I've made a mistake' and 'Have you forgotten'(Present Perfect)? The fact that he's forgotten is definetely conntected with the present i.e.: he can't come up with the right answer; the same goes for 'have made a mistake' - as a result he is giving the false information to the policeman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either way is grammatical.  Saying "*I have made a mistake*" is a little fatalistic.  It carries the sense that the speaker has done something wrong that is still affecting them, with no clear solution - they are *still* caught in the thralls of the mistake.

> Policeman: Did you kill your brother?
>
> Laton: I didn't shoot anybody!
>
> Policeman:  Who said anything about someone being shot?
>
> Laton: Egads! I have made a mistake!

Saying *"I made a mistake"* carries the sense that the mistake is a thing of the past, and the speaker believes it is now resolved - the mistake happened and is over.

> Policeman: Did you kill your brother?
>
> Laton: I don't have a brother.
>
> Policeman:  Oops  - I meant your cousin.  I made a mistake.

Comment: Is it worth considering the case of "I *had* made a mistake"?  In the original dialogue, once Mr. Laton recognizes the mistake, he is no longer making it.  The effect of the mistake can be placed purely in the past.  In the first dialogue here, the consequences of the mistake remain in the present.

Comment: what can be more fatalistic than having lied to a policeman? even unintendedly?:) @Adam